# Copy folder from iPhone Resources directory to document directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]autorelease];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                      NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentDBFolderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DB"];
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentDBFolderPath];

if (success){
 return;
}else{
 NSString *resourceDBFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                                         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DB"];
 [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath: documentDBFolderPath attributes:nil];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourceDBFolderPath toPath:documentDBFolderPath           
                                                                         error:&error];
 }
}
```

Like this.

Resources/DB/words.csv => DB folder copy => Document/DB/words.csv

I want to copy DB subdirectory at Resources folder. I thought that source is good. But that source makes folder and doesn't copy files in DB folder at Resources folder.

I really want to copy files in DB folder at Resources folder. please help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) **Do not `-autorelease` the `NSFileManager`**. You are double-releasing it which will crash your app.

2) No need to call `-createDirectoryAtPath:`. From the SDK doc of `-copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:`,

> The file specified in *srcPath* must exist, while *dstPath* **must not exist** prior to the operation

and creating the directory the copy to fail.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0**

Using String

```
func copyFolder(){

    // Get the resource folder
    if let resourceMainPath = Bundle.main.resourcePath{

        var isDirectory = ObjCBool(true)
        // Get the path of the folder to copy
        let originPath = (resourceMainPath as NSString).appendingPathComponent("NameOfFolder")
        // Get the destination path, here copying to Caches
        let destinationPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
        // Append the folder name to dest path so that system creates the directory if it doesnt exist
        let destPath = (destinationPath as NSString).appendingPathComponent("/NameOfFolder")
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destPath, isDirectory:&isDirectory ){
            // If an overwrite behavior is needed, remove and copy again here
             print("Exists")
        }else{
            // Do the copy
            do {
                try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: originPath, toPath: destPath)
            }catch let error{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }else{

    }

}
```

Using URL

```
func copyTheFolder(){

    // Get the resource folder
    if let resourceMainURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL{
        var isDirectory = ObjCBool(true)
        // Get the path of the folder to copy
        let originPath = resourceMainURL.appendingPathComponent("NameOfFolder")
        // Get the destination path, here copying to Caches
        let destinationPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
        // Append the folder name to dest path so that system creates the directory if it doesnt exist
        let destURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: destinationPath).appendingPathComponent("/NameOfFolder")
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destURL.path, isDirectory:&isDirectory ){
            // If an overwrite behavior is needed, remove and copy again here
            print("Exists")

        }else{
            // Do the copy
            do {
                try fileManager.copyItem(at: originPath, to: destURL)

            }catch let error{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```