# How to copy contents of a directory into a another directory programmatically in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, copy, nsfilemanager

I have 2 directories which are created programmatically, say DIR1 & DIR2 and DIR1 have some XML files now I need to copy the contents of DIR! into DIR2 without giving the Contents name

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `- (BOOL)copyItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath error:(NSError **)error` method to copy. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171230/copy-folder-from-iphone-resources-directory-to-document-directory) link. It will help you.

Comment: ya but here in src path we need to give the file name like  DIR1/file.xml,, but i dont want to mention directory contents name